# eventlet.green.urllib2 module not found

Tags: python, eventlet

I'm trying to run the very first code example on http://eventlet.net/doc/examples.html, `webcrawler.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
This is a simple web "crawler" that fetches a bunch of urls using a pool to
control the number of outbound connections. It has as many simultaneously open
connections as coroutines in the pool.

The prints in the body of the fetch function are there to demonstrate that the
requests are truly made in parallel.
"""
import eventlet
from eventlet.green import urllib2


urls = [
    "https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif",
    "http://python.org/images/python-logo.gif",
    "http://us.i1.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/ww/beta/y3.gif",
]


def fetch(url):
    print("opening", url)
    body = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    print("done with", url)
    return url, body


pool = eventlet.GreenPool(200)
for url, body in pool.imap(fetch, urls):
    print("got body from", url, "of length", len(body))
```

However, this leads to a

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'
```

I'm using eventlet version 0.21.0. Has this module moved within eventlet?

Answer (score 3):

The examples appear to be outdated (and now even more so).

For python 2, use this:

```
import eventlet
from eventlet.green import urllib2 as request

request.urlopen(...)
```

For python 3, use this:

```
import eventlet
from eventlet.green.urllib import request

request.urlopen(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally switched my build system (in Sublime Editor) to Python 2 instead of Python 3. Now it runs as expected:

```
('opening', 'https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif')
('opening', 'http://python.org/images/python-logo.gif')
('opening', 'http://us.i1.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/ww/beta/y3.gif')
('done with', 'https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif')
('got body from', 'https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif', 'of length', 8558)
('done with', 'http://us.i1.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/ww/beta/y3.gif')
('done with', 'http://python.org/images/python-logo.gif')
('got body from', 'http://python.org/images/python-logo.gif', 'of length', 2549)
('got body from', 'http://us.i1.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/ww/beta/y3.gif', 'of length', 1874)
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

Incidentally, this shows that the green threads are running asynchronously as intended.

Answer (score 0):

`eventlet.green` package mimicks Python stdlib module hierarchy.

Python2 has urllib2 module.
Python3 has urllib package with detailed submodules.

General idea: see normal Python code, change blocking modules import with `eventlet.green` version or `mod = eventlet.import_patched('mod')` and enjoy.